# set date according to value from form

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to get a date value from a form. What I tried to do here is to get the value then compare that value to a regular expression. Then I tried to create a date object where I set the date value to the result of the match. My console just returns `NaN`, even when I enter the correct format. Any ideas on how I can modify this so that I can set the date value correctly?

```
var adate = document.getElementById("dueDate").value;
var datestring = new RegExp("[0-9]{4}\\.\[0-9]{2}\\.\[0-9]{2}");
var stringmatch = adate.match(datestring);
var date = (new Date()).setDate(stringmatch);
console.log(date);
if (checkInputText(date, "Please enter a due date")) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when I change up the regex a little and do this, I get a value for stringmatch and date, with yours I don't.

```
     var adate = "11/09/2288";
     var datestring = /^(\d{2}[.\/-])(\d{2})([.\/-]\d{4})$/;
     var stringmatch = adate.match(datestring);
     var d = new Date(stringmatch[0]);
     var date = d.setDate(stringmatch[2]);
```

Date.setDate(day)  <-- usage, I am not sure what you are trying to do here. In my hardcoded date, would you want "09" to be setDate? I am trying to wrap my brain around what you are trying to accomplish.